# Java USB 56k modem get caller id

Tags: java, serial-port, modem, caller-id

I'm developing a windows application and I'm trying to retrieve the caller ID.

I have a 56k usb modem connected to my laptop which is connected to the telephone socket. How do I go about communicating with the modem (which is connected at COM5) through java code?

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortEvent;
import jssc.SerialPortEventListener;
import jssc.SerialPortException;
import jssc.SerialPortList;

public class ComControl {

    static SerialPort serialPort;
    private static Object line;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          //Method getPortNames() returns an array of strings. Elements of the array is already sorted.
        String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
        for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
            System.out.println(portNames[i]);           
        }

        serialPort = new SerialPort("COM5"); 
        try {
            serialPort.openPort();
            serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);

            serialPort.writeString("ATZ\r\n");
            //serialPort.readString();
            System.out.println(serialPort.readString());


        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

The above code is what I have at the moment. How do I retrieve the response after I send a command to the serial port?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve a response then you need to read from the port like so `serialPort.readBytes(bufferLength);`. Depending on your buffer length you will need to read several times to get the whole result and piece it together yourself.

Here is an example from the official example page:

```
import jssc.SerialPort; import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
        try {
            serialPort.openPort();//Open serial port
            serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);//Set params.
            byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(10);//Read 10 bytes from serial port
            serialPort.closePort();//Close serial port
        }
        catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The official javadoc seems to be offline, but you can find a bit of info here: https://www.java-forums.org/new-java/36167-serial-port-communication-via-jssc.html

Take note of example 3 for the SerialPortEventListener. Using a listener is the best way to manage a buffer.